# How to refresh select list after AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm populating a `select` list from a database via AJAx response. The DOM is updating properly but the list is still empty when I click it. I tried following other examples here but none helped.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal" id="linkLocationModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-success">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Select New Location</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="addLocationForm" action="/addProviderLocation" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="locationSelect">Location</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <select class="form-control" name="locationSelect" id="locationSelect" required multiple>
              </select>
              <input type="text" hidden id="h2providerid" name="h2providerid" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Link</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#linkLocationModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/locations"
  }).done(function(html) {
    $('#locationSelect').html('');

    $.each(html, function(val, text) {
      $('#locationSelect').append($('<option></option>').val(text.id).html(text.locationname));
    });
  });
});
```

If I try to append to the select list outside of the 'on' event, it works well. My goal of course it to populate the list dynamically from the db.

**Data returned from ajax request:**
2 Second Test Location
19 Lincoln (McBee St)
16 Guilford (Bellemeade Center)
24 Robeson (Godwin Avenue)
5 Davidson (Grimes Blvd)

DOM:

```
<select class="form-control" name="locationSelect" id="locationSelect" required="" multiple="" data-fv-field="locationSelect" style="display: none;"><option value="2">Second Test Location</option><option value="19">Lincoln (McBee St)</option><option value="16">Guilford (Bellemeade Center)</option><option value="24">Robeson (Godwin Avenue)</option><option value="5">Davidson (Grimes Blvd)</option><option value="3">Mecklenburg (Charlotte East)</option></select>
```

Comment: `$('locationSelect').append` did you mean `$('#locationSelect').append`?

Comment: Yes I meant to include this in the paste here. I also updated the html to show the modal and avoid confusion.

Comment: you're appending empty `<option>` elements.

Comment: It looks right! Can wee see the data returned from your ajax request?

Comment: Description updated with data returned from ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working.  Using the [plugin](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect) , I needed to rebuild the select list using the provided functions. The following code was moved after the loop to append the :

```
$('#addLocationForm')
              .find('[name="locationSelect"]')
              .multiselect({
                enableFiltering: true,
                includeSelectAllOption: true,
                // Re-validate the multiselect field when it is changed
                onChange: function (element, checked) {
                  $('#addLocationForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'locationSelect');
                }
              })
              .end();﻿
```